# Implementing a Bing Search TextBox or an address bar TextBox in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

There are many cases where you need the TextBox height to be static (i.e its default value). The problem is that when the user is allowed to put unlimited string inside the scrolling method provided is not so friendly.

So far what I have managed to do is:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroller" MaxWidth="416" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <TextBox x:Name="Tb" TextChanged="TextBox_OnTextChanged" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="25" MaxWidth="2048"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And the code behind:

```
    private void TextBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         // if cursor is at the end of the text, scroll the ScrollViewer to the end 
        if (Tb.SelectionStart == Tb.Text.Length)
        {
            Scroller.ScrollToVerticalOffset(Tb.ActualHeight);
            return;
        }

        // else scroll to the appropriate spot
        if (!((Tb.SelectionStart * (Tb.ActualWidth / Tb.Text.Length) - Scroller.HorizontalOffset) < Scroller.ViewportWidth))
        {
            Scroller.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((Tb.SelectionStart) * (Tb.ActualWidth / Tb.Text.Length) - (Scroller.ViewportWidth - 55));
        }
    }
```

However this is not solid yet. It has a problem when the Tb.ActualWidth reaches its limit and the scrolling experience when moving the caret in the middle of the text is not the same as the Bing Search Box.

Is there a way to add the same functionality as Bing search box or the address bar in IE on windows phone 8?